# HTTP Error 403.14 Forbidden in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I run my site on local. My site worked fine until yesterday but today I get following error:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

I search in internet and found any question like this, but its answers not solution for my problem.

I try following in administrator but not slolved my problem:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

Comment: You didn't post enough information for us to understand. At least can you remember what did you change "yesterday"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a Default Page, for example, a Login Page, to be shown when the server is started?

If not, set an aspx page in your Web.config file as a start up page.

Comment: I use mvc 4 . how to get it?

Comment: Check your RouteConfig file. Check the Controller Name and Action Name associated with that. 
Check for this:-
 defaults:=New With {.controller = "ContollerName", .action = "ActionName"} _
        )